# Adding CSS to the input (type = text) in the form under a DIV

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a following form on which I want a add an autocomplete=off to any input with type text.

(In the following code I have one such input though)

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="user-login">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
        <label for="edit-name">Username </label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60" class="form-text required">

    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
        <label for="edit-pass">Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">

    </div>
... </form>
....
```

What I am hoping to do is to add an autocomplete in the input of type text in the div under the form with ID user-login.

This is what I tried:-

```
if ($("#user-login").length){
           //$("div.messages h2").prop('nextSibling').nodeValue = "Please log in with the information received in the email. Thank you.";
            $("form#user-login").children("input:first").css('autocomplete','off');
            console.log("done");
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

use `.prop` to set autocomplete property

```
$("form#user-login").find("input:first").prop('autocomplete','off');
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Faisal .. See Edited answer.. try that